# Can't hide tableview header area

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tableview with this awkward gap between the top of the first section and the nav bar. I tried the following solutions I found online to hide the section but none seem to be working here:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame = CGRect.zero
```

also tried adding

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return nil
}
```

Neither seem to work. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Set `heightForHeaderInSection` to `.leastNonzeroMagnitude`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in viewDidLoad:

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    yourTableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
} else {
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = CGFloat(0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize.zero
}
```